# Add JButton only to a specific JTable cell (or more)

Tags: java, jtable, jbutton

I wanna add a button to some specific cells where i might get null characters from my database. I tried overriding 'TableCellRenderer' . But it keep adding buttons to entire column. What should i do? (example wd b better)

Answer (score 0):

> But it keep adding buttons to entire column.

Yes, a renderer is designed to work for the entire column.

If you want a different renderer for a different row then you can override the `getCellRenderer(...)` method. Something like:

```
public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
{
    Object value = getValueAt(row, column);

    if (value == null)
    {
        return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
    }
    else
        return getDefaultRenderer(value.getClass());

}
```

You would also need similar code for the `getCellEditor(...)` method.

You can also check out Table Button Column for an example of a button renderer/editor.